# Using zfill to pad a Colum of numbers based on a string in a column of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to zfill based on 2 column's in my Dataframe. The first column is called unit and it only contains 2 strings, 'Metric' and 'Imperial'.

The second column is called closing which has loads of numbers in it. However if Colum one is metric I need the numbers to zfill to 5 and if its imperial i need to zfill to 4. Example:
Metric: 23 needs to become 00023.
Imperial: 23 needs to become 0023

Basically,
if column one (unit) = Metric, then I want to look at column two (closing) and zfill to 5
if column one (unit) = Imperia, then I want to look at column two (closing) and zfill to 4

This is the current code, however I'm getting the error: 'function' object has no attribute 'astype'

```
df['Unit'] == 'Metric', df['closing'].replace.astype(str).zfill(5)
df['Unit'] == 'Imperial', df['closing'].replace.astype(str).zfill(4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you have only two choices (`Metric`, `Imperial`) to choose from, you could use Numpy [`where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

Input *sample.csv*

```py
       Unit  closing
0  Imperial       20
1    Metric      284
2  Imperial     1451
3  Imperial       45
4    Metric     8491
```

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')

df['closing'] = np.where(df['Unit'] == 'Metric',
     df['closing'].astype(str).str.zfill(5),
     df['closing'].astype(str).str.zfill(4),
)

print(df)
```

Output from *df*

```py
       Unit closing
0  Imperial    0020
1    Metric   00284
2  Imperial    1451
3  Imperial    0045
4    Metric   08491
```

Comment: Thanks this is a great solution!